# Can't log in to Ubuntu machine

Tags: command-line, login-screen

I'm having a bit of an issue with my Ubuntu laptop right now. I opened it to log in and it got stuck after I entered my password... my current theory is that I don't have enough disk space as I was making a ton of back-ups on my VM last night.

I hit ctrl-alt-f1 to get to a command line. However, it wants me to log in. I may have forgotten my username for my account. Is there a way to get this? No matter how many versions of it I try, it won't accept my credentials.

What's the best way to get back in to my machine?

Comment: is the username not shown in the graphical login? - else you could use a live medium and check for the name of the folder after `/home/`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank. It was the low disk space for me.

what I did what Ctrl+Alt+F1 then loged in by user and pass, Then run

`sudo apt-get clean`

with pass again.

Happy Shavoo'ot